# How to configure log4j.xml for migrating from log4j to log4j2?

Tags: java, struts2, log4j, log4j2

I am working on a application that was using `log4j` until now and I want to migrate to `log4j2`. I am a new to using `log4j 2`, referring the `log4j 1.x migration guide` but for some parts I am not clear about how the configuration in my `log4j.xml` should be.

Current `log4j.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    
    <!-- Appender for logging to console output  -->
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}][%5p][%c{1}:%L]- %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <!-- Appender for logging audit messages to the file  -->
    <appender name="auditLoggerAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="C:/logs/Filename.log" /> 
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="C:/logs/Filename2.%d.log" />   
            <param name="MaxHistory" value="30" />  
        </rollingPolicy>
        
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}][%5p][%c{1}:%L]- %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <!-- Logger for audit messages -->
    <logger name="auditLogger" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="applicationLoggerAppender" />        
    </logger>
    
    
</log4j:configuration>
```

what configuration changes need to be made for `<param>`, `<layout>`, the `<RollinFileAppender>` part and `<logger name="auditLogger" additivity="false"> <appender-ref ref="applicationLoggerAppender" />         </logger>` for it to work with log4j 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Log4j2 basically two aspects change in the XML configuration:

- component types are not identified using their class name, but their plugin name. E.g. to create a `RollingFileAppender` (cf. [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html)) you'll use `RollingFile` instead of `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender`,
- all simple properties of a component are specified as XML attributes.

The concise version of your appender (cf. [concise and string XML config])(https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_XML) will be:

```xml
    <RollingFile name="auditLoggerAppender"
                 fileName="C:\logs\Filename.log"
                 filePattern="C:\logs\Filename2.%d.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS}][%5p][%c{1}:%L]- %m%n"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG"/>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

Loggers are configured in a similar way:

```xml
    <Logger name="auditLogger" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="auditLoggerAppender" />
    </Logger>
```

You can find all configuration properties either in the [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/overview-summary.html) or the [XSD schema](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd).